# Splitting nasty list FAILED

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I am still a beginner with Mathematica and I have a simple problem with splitting this list:

```
List1 = {"Id=\"1\"", "PostTypeId=\"1\"", "AcceptedAnswerId=\"2\"", \
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:22:07.323\"", "OwnerUserId=\"8\"", \
"LastEditorUserId=\"8\"", "Tags=\"&lt;word-choice&gt;&lt;articles&gt;\
\"", "Id=\"2\"", "PostTypeId=\"2\"", "ParentId=\"1\"", "CreationDate=\
\"2013-11-05T20:36:02.473\"", "OwnerUserId=\"17\"", \
"LastEditorUserId=\"17\"", "Id=\"3\"", "PostTypeId=\"2\"", "ParentId=\
\"1\"", "CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:37:28.327\"", \
"OwnerUserId=\"6\"", "Id=\"4\"", "PostTypeId=\"2\"", \
"ParentId=\"1\"", "CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:38:07.760\"", \
"OwnerUserId=\"18\"", "LastEditorUserId=\"8\"", "Id=\"5\"", \
"PostTypeId=\"1\"", "CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:46:59.993\"", \
"OwnerUserId=\"18\"", "LastEditorUserId=\"707\"", \
"Tags=\"&lt;etymology&gt;&lt;proverbs&gt;\"", "Id=\"6\"", \
"PostTypeId=\"1\"", "AcceptedAnswerId=\"8\"", \
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:01:56.857\"", "OwnerUserId=\"18\"", \
"LastEditorUserId=\"707\"", \
"Tags=\"&lt;grammar&gt;&lt;grammatical-number&gt;\"", "Id=\"8\"", \
"PostTypeId=\"2\"", "ParentId=\"6\"", \
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:09:18.067\"", "OwnerUserId=\"6\"", \
"LastEditorUserId=\"1243\"", "Id=\"9\"", "PostTypeId=\"2\"", \
"ParentId=\"6\"", "CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:15:24.207\"", \
"OwnerUserId=\"22\"", "LastEditorUserId=\"57\"", "Id=\"10\""}
```

What I would like to do is divide the list in such a way that I have a lists with only: List1 = {{Id1, CreationDate1, Tags1},{Id2, CreationDate2, Tags2},{Id3, CreationDate3, Tags3}...}.

The approach I tried is to split on the `&gt;\"`. Unfortunately this doesn't work. Can someone help me in finding a quick way to do it? (as plus, it would nice if we could get rid of `&alt;` and `&gt;` in somehow)

I hereby post the code I used

```
StringSplit[StringJoin[{List1}], "&gt;\""]
```

But it doesn't help a lot, since then I have to get back then to the original list with another StringSplit. I am sure there is a smarter way I am not able to see here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try `Partition[List1,3]`

Comment: It doesn't work because not all the records have "Tags".
Note: A record is from id to tag (when is present)

Comment: `StringSplit` only works on strings, not lists.

Comment: @user6014 I am not sure you're right. Take a look to the documentation center. It states that "StringSplit automatically threads over lists of strings:" and uses as example: StringSplit[{"a:b:c:d", "listable:element"}, ":"] which works perfectly.

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake. I apologize.

Comment: The presence of entities like `&gt;` suggests that the source data was XML or HTML.  If the original markup is available, then `Import[..., "XMLObject"]` (or `ImportString`) might be easier to work with.

Comment: @WReach Not really when you have GB of data to work with.. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this does help?

```
list = Most[List1];
pos = Flatten[Position[StringTake[#, 1 ;; 3] & /@ list, "Id="]];
AppendTo[pos, Length[list] + 1];
data =
  Map[
   Association[Rule @@@ StringSplit[#, "="]] &,
   Internal`PartitionRagged[
    list,
    Differences[pos]
    ]
   ];
data = MapAt[DateObject, data, {All, "CreationDate"}];
newdata = data[[All, {"Id", "CreationDate", "Tags"}]];
newdata = MapAt[
  If[! MissingQ[#], StringReplace[#, {"&lt;" -> "<", "&gt;" -> ">"}],# ] &, 
  newdata, 
  {All, "Tags"}
  ]
```

Comment: This is really nice! The only thing I am sure about is the function To Associations, because on my Mathematica does not exist. Could you please take a look? However, thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: Ah right, one has to load ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]``. But I removed `ToAssociations` altogether. Have look.

Comment: It's perfect, love it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

uses `ReplaceRepeated` in a recursive manner to generate the lists

```
StringReplace[
Cases[List1, 
x_ /; StringStartsQ[x, ("Id" | "CreationDate" | "Tags")]], 
"&gt;" | "&lt;" -> ""] //. {p___, x_ /; StringStartsQ[x, "Id"], y__,z_ /;
StringStartsQ[z, "Id"], t___} :> {p, {x, y}, z, t}

(* {{"Id=\"1\"", "CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:22:07.323\"", 
"Tags=\"word-choicearticles\""}, {"Id=\"2\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:36:02.473\""}, {"Id=\"3\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:37:28.327\""}, {"Id=\"4\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:38:07.760\""}, {"Id=\"5\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T20:46:59.993\"", 
"Tags=\"etymologyproverbs\""}, {"Id=\"6\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:01:56.857\"", 
"Tags=\"grammargrammatical-number\""}, {"Id=\"8\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:09:18.067\""}, {"Id=\"9\"", 
"CreationDate=\"2013-11-05T21:15:24.207\""}, "Id=\"10\""} *)
```